# Bloch's theorem for Semi-Infinite Lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, lattice-model, matrix-model

If we have a lattice Hamiltonian $$ \sum_{n'\in\mathbb{Z}}H_{n,n'}\psi_{n'} = E\psi_{n} \,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z} $$
such that $ H_{n,n'} = H_{n+q,n'+q}$ for some $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $\left(n,n'\right)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ then Bloch's theorem tells us that the eigenfunctions of this Hamiltonian $\psi_n$ will be of the form $\psi_{n,k} = \exp(ikn)u_{n,k}$ where $k\in[0,\frac{2\pi}{q}]$ and $u_{n,k}=u_{n+q,k}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The nice thing about this is that then we can instead diagonalize a $q\times q$ matrix $H_k$ given by the $\left(j,j'\right)$ component (for all $\left(j,j'\right)\in(\mathbb{Z}_q)^2$): $$ \left(H_k\right)_{j,j'} = \sum_{m\in q\mathbb{Z}} H_{j,m+j'}\exp\left(ikm\right) $$

When working on *half* a lattice, that is, $$ \sum_{n'\in\mathbb{N}}H_{n,n'}\psi_{n'} = E\psi_{n} \,\forall n\in\mathbb{N} $$ (where still $ H_{n,n'} = H_{n+q,n'+q}$ for the same $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $\left(n,n'\right)\in\mathbb{N}^2$), is there an analogue of the Bloch theorem?

Because $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ have a bijection between them, I should expect at least a generalization of Bloch's theorem, but I wasn't able to find something like that yet.

Comment: Just because N and Z are both countable, it doesn't mean that there is a bijection between them that will preserve the symmetries and structure of the Hamiltonian. You are much better off looking for ways to 'cut' the solution over Z in two in a way which will give two solutions over N, e.g. by taking superpositions of solutions for positive and negative $k$.

Comment: Any details on this cutting procedure? And why do you assume there will be two solutions over N (you mean one for the positive lattice and one for the negative lattice?)

Comment: I seem to recall that in such problems the Wiener-Hopf method can be used. But the discrete translational symmetry required for the Bloch theorem is lacking.